# What is boolean parameter convention in Javascript or React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React and I want to handle a simple setter by useState.

So for example,

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const handleIsOpen = (flag:boolean) => {
    setIsOpen(flag)
}
```

I cannot decide which name is proper to use instead of `flag`.

Is there any popular convention deciding a boolean parameter like this case?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the naming convention you can follow as below:

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const handleIsOpen = (toggleState:boolean) => {
    setIsOpen(toggleState)
}
```

It is not always compulsory to use this, but as standard practices and readability, you can prefer this.